# Appengine Basics

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, oauth-2.0

I am working building this application on google app engine that goes and gets a person's calendar.

Since I am new to google app engine and OAuth 2.0 this is the flow I've come up with:

1. Redirect to google accounts and get the `authorization_code` with
   `scope` set to calendars api
2. Exchange the code for an `access_token`
3. Use the token to get the calendar feed.

I have the authorization code but am stuck on step 2. The documentation says "do a post" to get the access token.  Is there an API that does this?

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

well, i guess "do a post" means http-post...

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet?hl=en

Comment: Thanks.....okay so I guess i made some progress in this direction today...at this point I have an access token.... but now i have an issue getting the userid of the person loggged in ...everytime i do a `request.getUserPrincipal() or UserServiceFactory.getCurrentuser()` it returns my own userid and not the user id of the person logged in ... is there I way I could get the user id of the person logged in???